# Any CUDA operation after cudaStreamSynchronize blocks until all streams are finished

Tags: c++, cuda

While profiling my CUDA application with NVIDIA Visual Profiler I noticed that any operation after `cudaStreamSynchronize` blocks until all streams are finished. This is very odd behavior because if `cudaStreamSynchronize` returns that means that the stream is finished, right? Here is my pseudo-code:

```
std::list<std::thread> waitingThreads;

void startKernelsAsync() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
        cudaHostAlloc(cpuPinnedMemory, size, cudaHostAllocDefault);
        memcpy(cpuPinnedMemory, data, size);
        cudaMalloc(gpuMemory);

        cudaStreamCreate(&stream);
        cudaMemcpyAsync(gpuMemory, cpuPinnedMemory, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream);
        runKernel<<<32, 32, 0, stream>>>(gpuMemory);
        cudaMemcpyAsync(cpuPinnedMemory, gpuMemory, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, stream);

        waitingThreads.push_back(std::move(std::thread(waitForFinish, cpuPinnedMemory, stream)));
    }

    while (waitingThreads.size() > 0) {
        waitingThreads.front().join();
        waitingThreads.pop_front();
    }
}

void waitForFinish(void* cpuPinnedMemory, cudaStream_t stream, ...) {
    cudaStreamSynchronize(stream);
    cudaStreamDestroy(stream);  // <== This blocks until all streams are finished.
    memcpy(data, cpuPinnedMemory, size);
    cudaFreeHost(cpuPinnedMemory);
    cudaFree(gpuMemory);
}
```

If I put `cudaFreeHost` before `cudaStreamDestroy` then it becomes the blocking operation.

Is there anything conceptually wrong here?

EDIT: I found another weird behavior, sometimes it un-blocks in the middle of processing of streams and then processes the rest of streams.

Normal behavior:

[image: Normal behavior]

Strange behavior (happens quite often):

[image: Strange behavior]

EDIT2: I am testing on Tesla K40c card with compute capability 3.5 on CUDA 6.0.

As suggested in comments, it may be viable to reduce number of streams however in my application the memory transfers are quite fast and I want to use streams mainly to dynamically schedule work to GPU. The problem is that after stream finishes I need to download data from pinned memory and clear allocated memory for further streams which seems to be blocking operation.

I am using one stream per data-set because every data-set has different size and processing takes unpredictably long time.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Aren't you implicitly assuming that host driver level operations like stream destruction and pinned memory release can be performed while the GPU is busy? Do you have any reason to assume that they should be non-blocking?

Comment: @talonmies I do, you are right. However, in order to use streams you have to use pinned memory and if the operations on streams and pinned memory would be blocking then it's not very useful. Also, operations like `cudaStreamCreate`, `cudaHostAlloc`, and `cudaMalloc` are working just fine even though GPU is busy.

Comment: I think memory free operations (`cudaFree`, `cudaHostFree`) may be blocking.  I wouldn't be surprised if `cudaStreamDestroy` is blocking also.  I think your statement that "if the operations on streams and pinned memory would be blocking then it's not very useful", might be better appended with "for me."  A typical usage scenario for memory allocations, free operations, and stream create/destroy, is to do these at the beginning and at the end of your application, in areas that are not performance sensitive to blocking. They may not work well for this particular code design.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Allocating at the beginning and freeing at the end may be typical in non-streamed CUDA applications but imagine situation that you have 1 TB of data that you want to crunch using CUDA and streams. Then, waiting for "the end" is not an option and everything has to be done "while GPU is busy". I was hoping that CUDA streams actually support this kind of application but I might be wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I don't agree with your analysis.  Having 1 TB of data in no way restricts me from making allocations up front.  From a performance standpoint, memory allocations are expensive, even in CPU code, so making a large number of small allocations is generally slower than making a few large allocations and organizing and re-using them yourself.   Most CUDA apps handling arbitrary data sizes, and working on a single GPU, require at most 3 or 4 streams to get full performance and concurrency.

Comment: @RobertCrovella So could you try to suggest (in an answer) how to re-rewrite the pseudo-code using 3-4 streams? The problem might be that the size of data for every stream vary as well as processing time per stream.

Comment: I would start with [this presentation](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf). Especially slide 22.  In effect it is just rotating through and re-using 3 streams in a round-robin fashion.  If time permits, I will come back and re-write your pseudocode.  And I consider spinning up multiple host threads unnecessary for this as well.

Comment: The referenced presentation is severely out dated and will not support full concurrency for kernels that do not reach full GPU occupancy. The driver does have a maximum number of streams as streams require additional host and device memory allocations. Once the driver limit is exceeded the driver aliases work from multiple streams to existing streams in order to limit the memory allocations. CC 2.0 can support 16 simultaneous kernels and 2 copy copies. These number increase as you move to newer GPUs. On GK110 (K40) you may find increasing the communication channels from 8 to 32 helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found why the operations are blocking but I concluded that I can not do anything about it so I decided ti implement memory and streams pooling (as suggested in comments) to re-use GPU memory, pinned CPU memory and streams to avoid any kind of deletion.

In case anybody would be interested here is my solution. The start kernel behaves as asynchronous operation that schedules kernel and callback is called after the kernel is finished.

```
std::vector<Instance*> m_idleInstances;
std::vector<Instance*> m_workingInstances;

void startKernelAsync(...) {
    // Search for finished stream.
    while (m_idleInstances.size() == 0) {
        findFinishedInstance();
        if (m_idleInstances.size() == 0) {
            std::chrono::milliseconds dur(10);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(dur);
        }
    }

    Instance* instance = m_idleInstances.back();
    m_idleInstances.pop_back();

    // Fill CPU pinned memory

    cudaMemcpyAsync(..., stream);
    runKernel<<<32, 32, 0, stream>>>(gpuMemory);
    cudaMemcpyAsync(..., stream);

    m_workingInstances.push_back(clusteringInstance);
}

void findFinishedInstance() {
    for (auto it = m_workingInstances.begin(); it != m_workingInstances.end();) {
        Instance* inst = *it;
        cudaError_t status = cudaStreamQuery(inst->stream);
        if (status == cudaSuccess) {
            it = m_workingInstances.erase(it);
            m_callback(instance->clusterGroup);
            m_idleInstances.push_back(inst);
        }
        else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

And at the and just wait for everybody to finish:

```
virtual void waitForFinish() {
    while (m_workingInstances.size() > 0) {
        Instance* instance = m_workingInstances.back();
        m_workingInstances.pop_back();
        m_idleInstances.push_back(instance);
        cudaStreamSynchronize(instance->stream);
        finalizeInstance(instance);
    }
}
```

And here is a graph form profiler, works as a charm!

[image: Graph of streams]

Answer (score 0):

Check out the list of "Implicit Synchronization" rules in the Cuda C Programming Guide PDF that comes with the toolkit.  (Section 3.2.5.5.4 in my copy, but you might have a different version.)

If your GPU is "compute capability 3.0 or lower", there are some special rules that apply. My guess would be that cudaStreamDestroy() is hitting one of those limitations.

Comment: I checked the Programming Guide but I haven't found anything that would address concretely my problem (and I am testing on compute capability 3.5). Thanks anyways.